# Rudin's Real Complex Analysis, Chapter 7, Theorem 7.26

Tags: measure-theory

Should "maximal segments" be replaced by "maximal intervals" on page $156$, in the derivation of the special case of theorem $7.26$ from Rudin's Real Complex Analysis, $3$rd edition?

The reason I ask is because if the function phi is constant on say $[c, d]$, the maximal segment will be $(c, d)$ which will lead to "c" and "d" belonging to $X$ and phi wont be $1-1$ on $X$ (which is required to use theorem $7.26$).

However, if we use maximal intervals, the maximal interval will be $[c, d]$, which will lead to phi being $1-1$ on $X$.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have the book - okay, I do, digitally,  but others may not have it. Please include the statement of the theorem in your question.

Comment: in the line defining $X$, if you interpret the existence of $\phi'$ to be where both left and right derivatives of $\phi$ exist and agree, then "maximal segments" is fine since the left and right derivatives of your endpoints $c$ and $d$ disagree thanks to maximality

Comment: Thanks @user363464 for your response. Lets take phi to be the following function: For the x leading up to "c", phi is like a sine curve leading up to x = pi/2, phi is constant (equal to 1) on [c, d] and then for x after "d", phi is like the sine curve after x = pi/2. Now in this case both the left and right derivatives at "c" and "d" exist and are equal to 0. So won't phi-dash exist on both "c" and "d"?

Comment: I think what I had in mind when I wrote my response was that once you remove the maximal segments, the derivative of $\phi$ becomes one-sided at the endpoints of the removed segments. Of course you are right, $\phi'$ exists in $V$ with your example, but not when restricted to $V - \Omega$ if you require differentiability on both ends. But now that I write this, I feel my guess is somewhat of a stretch.

In any case, the issue is rectified if, as you propose, you remove maximal intervals instead of segments.

Comment: Thanks @user363464 for sharing your thoughts. I am glad that I am not the only one who thinks this way :)